# Filter ajax request by proxy

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, proxy

I have a proxy where i want to proxify `ajax` requests i have found that code and it works good:

```
(function() {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

          function parseURI(url) {
            var m = String(url).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").match(/^([^:\/?#]+:)?(\/\/(?:[^:@]*(?::[^:@]*)?@)?(([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#[\s\S]*)?/);
            // authority = "//" + user + ":" + pass "@" + hostname + ":" port
            return (m ? {
              href : m[0] || "",
              protocol : m[1] || "",
              authority: m[2] || "",
              host : m[3] || "",
              hostname : m[4] || "",
              port : m[5] || "",
              pathname : m[6] || "",
              search : m[7] || "",
              hash : m[8] || ""
            } : null);
          }

          function rel2abs(base, href) { // RFC 3986

            function removeDotSegments(input) {
              var output = [];
              input.replace(/^(\.\.?(\/|$))+/, "")
                .replace(/\/(\.(\/|$))+/g, "/")
                .replace(/\/\.\.$/, "/../")
                .replace(/\/?[^\/]*/g, function (p) {
                  if (p === "/..") {
                    output.pop();
                  } else {
                    output.push(p);
                  }
                });
              return output.join("").replace(/^\//, input.charAt(0) === "/" ? "/" : "");
            }

            href = parseURI(href || "");
            base = parseURI(base || "");

            return !href || !base ? null : (href.protocol || base.protocol) +
            (href.protocol || href.authority ? href.authority : base.authority) +
            removeDotSegments(href.protocol || href.authority || href.pathname.charAt(0) === "/" ? href.pathname : (href.pathname ? ((base.authority && !base.pathname ? "/" : "") + base.pathname.slice(0, base.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + href.pathname) : base.pathname)) +
            (href.protocol || href.authority || href.pathname ? href.search : (href.search || base.search)) +
            href.hash;

          }

          var proxied = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
          window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
              if (arguments[1] !== null && arguments[1] !== undefined) {
                var url = arguments[1];
                url = rel2abs("' . $url . '", url);
                url = "' . PROXY_PREFIX . '" + url;
                arguments[1] = url;
              }
              return proxied.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
          };

        }

      })();
```

But the problem is that i also have some `ajax` request which i dont need to `proxyify` but i use `XMLHttpRequest` too...

And the question is how can i filter my `ajax` requests and ignore them in that `javascript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a public interface to access the proxied `open` call:

```
var proxied = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open_noproxy = proxied;
```

Then you can call `XMLHttpRequest::open_noproxy()` when you want to make a normal AJAX call.

Another way would be to put a keyword in the URL, e.g. `NOPROXY:http://whatever`. Your replacement `open` function can check whether the URL begins with `NOPROXY:`; if so, it removes it from the URL and then skips over the code that adds the proxy prefix before calling `proxied`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i have found another way, if i know my `url` which im trying to `ajax` im checking them by `arguments[1] != "http://mysite.co/ajax.php"` anyway i think your way is better.

Comment: I thought you were looking for something more general than that obvious solution.